# New job to begin Monday has been rescinded due to 'incorrect employment dates' - this is my response, what do you think?

Tags: job-offer, united-kingdom, background-check, pre-screening

Today my dream died.

After the enthralling experience of meeting yourself and the entire team, all I have dreamt of since being given an offer was working with all of you. Sadly, this was not meant to be.

I can confirm I have received a notice of withdrawal of offer at my home address this evening.

Thanks for all your help.

I wish to thank you for bringing me this wonderful opportunity.

Also, my heartfelt thanks to entire team whom I met over the course of phone and in-person interviews for their time and effort.

After the withdrawal of the offer today I am in total limbo.

It is hugely annoying and upsetting to have the carpet swept from under my feet as a consequence of a typo on my CV.

All I have focused on over the last 6-8 weeks was joining the team.

With the bad timing of this withdrawal it would be very difficult for me if I don’t receive another offer soon.

I am keen to get your advice about restarting my job search and would like to be in your consideration for future openings at xxxx.

Thanks, xxxx.

Kind regards,

xxxx

Comment: Do you know (for sure) what they even mean by "incorrect employment dates"?  How bad was this "typo" on your CV?

Comment: One of my employments was off by a month another by 3 weeks. Its my error but what was I supposed to have tried to gain from this?

Comment: You might as well post your resume directly on StackExchange so that other potential employers can offer you employment.  Be sure to add salary requirements.

Comment: Instead of wasting your time with this letter I would focus on carefully reviewing your CV and correcting any more typos/errors before you next apply to a company.

Comment: Are you sure that those discrepancies are why the offer was withdrawn?  I've seen and heard of some strange behaviors but I can't imagine a company caring about a couple weeks one way or another on your job history.

Comment: "What do you think" is inherently opinion-based and off topic for the Q&A format here. Is there a specific objective you have? Or a less subjective question you're trying to ask?

Comment: A much more appropriate question for this site would've been asking how to respond (without giving your proposed response). Although they've already taken action, so there's unlikely to be a difference in what you gain from giving a bad response, a good response or just no response (although unlikely doesn't mean impossible). If you want opinions on some action you're planning on taking, somewhere like Reddit would be a much better place to ask.

Answer (score 28):

This is a terrible letter to send.  Don't do it.  It reads as deeply emotional, overdramatic, crying out for sympathy, while downplaying your own fault in vague terms.  If I got a letter like that from someone I'd considered a new hire after HR had put a block on it, I would be thankful that I had dodged a bullet, because I'd assume that they would have generated significant amounts of drama once they arrived.

If your CV date issues really were a typo or similar, then I'd think that you might be able to rescue the situation by calling HR (or whoever) and pleading your case (preferably in less dramatic tones) but my suspicion based on what you've said is that that's not what's going on.  Being off by a month or a few weeks on your CV is trivial unless you're *extremely* junior.  My guess is that if they're throwing you out after having made an offer with an extensive onboarding process, it's because they started to have other serious concerns after they made you the offer, and the inaccurate CV was only the easiest thing to point to, and hardest to argue with.

Assuming that's the case, a letter like the above is only going to confirm their earlier conclusions.  The appropriate reaction for you is twofold.  First, fix your resume, so that it's accurate.  Second, make sure that you're giving respect to the admin staff, respect their time, and try to behave in a more professional way (ie, less dramatic) when in a professional setting.  Start by swallowing your bile and *not* sending the letter.  It'll be good practice.

Comment: It is not only going to confirm that company's conclusions. It is going to make the OP more memorable, so the problem that caused the withdrawal will follow them around as people who have read the letter move to other companies.

Answer (score 14):

**You should absolutely NOT send the letter you proposed.**  Outside of the fact it has numerous grammatical and formatting mistakes.  It is absolutely not appropriate to send at this point.

The decision was made not to higher you due to inconsistency with your resume.  It does not really matter what the inconsistency was exactly, but a company does not typically spend resources interviewing a candidate for a job, then offering them a job, if that inconsistency is something they can accept as a simple typographical error.

The proposed letter also is extremely informal.  A statement like *After the withdrawal of the offer today I am in total limbo.* is never appropriate.  A statement like, **It is hugely annoying and upsetting to have the carpet swept from under my feet as a consequence of a typo on my CV.**, makes it sound like the error in your resume wasn't a big deal.

Here is a news flash, the typographical error in your resume was a big enough deal to rescind your offer, even after spending resources to interview you and offer you a position.  **In other words, the company lost money, rescinding your job offer.**

**You could send them a letter of appreciation for the opportunity, but leave the self-wallowing, to a phone call with your parents and/or significant other.**